# How to configure reportbug to use smtp password from gnome-keyring?

Tags: debian, gnome3, command-substitution, gnome-keyring, reportbug

When configuring `reportbug`, I have an option to store the password for the remote smtp service in `$HOME/.reportbugrc`. How can I make it use an existing password stored by GNOME Web (Epiphany) or Evolution in GNOME keyring instead, so that I do not need to update `$HOME/.reportbugrc` if the password in GNOME keyring changes?

I found that I can read the password from GNOME keyring with `secret-tools` command, which is provided by `libsecret-tools` package, and use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) with `$(…)` to invoke `secret-tools` and use its output like this:

```
$ reportbug --smtppasswd=$(secret-tool lookup uri https://webmail.example.invalid)
```

or this:

```
$ reportbug --smtppasswd=$(secret-tool lookup target_origin https://webmail.example.invalid username user@example.invalid)
```

Unfortunately, `reportbug` does not seem to perform substitution in `~/.reportbugrc`. I tried like this:

```
smtppasswd "$(secret-tool lookup target_origin https://webmail.example.invalid username user@example.invalid)"
```

Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up defining an alias in `~\.bash_aliases`.

```bash
alias reportbug-pass='reportbug --smtppasswd="$(secret-tool lookup eds-origin evolution-data-server e-source-uid 7f1e149e069bd66ab5aa1a734baa113943cdf0ee)"'
```

Using that alias instead of calling `reportbug` directly invokes reportbug with `--smtppasswd` already passed to it. Now, if I want to pass my SMTP password to `reportbug`, I can type that alias instead. You can pass other parameters to it, like the name of the package reported, as you would to `reportbug`.

```bash
$ reportbug-pass
```

Instead of an alias, the same result can be achieved by defining a function in `~\.bash_aliases`

```bash
function reportbug-pass() {
    reportbug --smtppasswd="$(secret-tool lookup eds-origin evolution-data-server e-source-uid pdljjhvbuo6uvc7mydavpmbjqqhxqq2jyhqdndpmcvamknbih8cifgfg)" "$@"
}
```

In this function, the `"$@"` parameter [expends to arguments passed to it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters), so that you could pass the name of the package, for example.

In this case, whether it is an alias or a function, the query against the keyring happens when you call it from the command line. If the keyring is locked, you get a usual graphical prompt to unlock the keyring.